# Multiple column labels or names

Tags: r, dataset, matrix

I want to put two rows of labels, or colnames, (either to a data frame or a matrix), like so:

```
  Big Big Medium Medium Low Low
  Wet Dry    Wet    Dry Wet Dry
1   6   4      1      3   2   5
2   4   4      1      3   1   6
3   4   3      1      3   1   6
4   5   2      1      2   1   4
5   3   4      1      2   3   5
```

and be able to refer to a given column by using the two labels, for example column "Medium","Dry".

Comment: You could concatenate the text from the first two rows into a single name for each column.  But I suspect that your real problem is more involved than this example.

Answer (score 4):

What you ask for doesn't exist. Names are always character vectors so they are always 1-dimensional. So either you use simply names like `"Big Wet"` in data frames/matrices or you have to use another data structure such as the a 3-dimensional array with the dimensions *size*, *wet/dry*, *row* where you can name them separately:

```
> array(c(6,4,4,5,3,4,4,3,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,5,6,6,4,5),
        c(5,2,3), list(1:5, c("Wet", "Dry"), c("Big", "Medium", "Low")))
, , Big

  Wet Dry
1   6   4
2   4   4
3   4   3
4   5   2
5   3   4

, , Medium

  Wet Dry
1   1   3
2   1   3
3   1   3
4   1   2
5   1   2

, , Low

  Wet Dry
1   2   5
2   1   6
3   1   6
4   1   4
5   3   5

> a[, "Wet",]
  Big Medium Low
1   6      1   2
2   4      1   1
3   4      1   1
4   5      1   1
5   3      1   3

> a[, "Dry", "Medium"]
1 2 3 4 5 
3 3 3 2 2
```

Comment: can you take this example a little further and describe how you'd store it if the columns have different data types (like a data.frame allows)?  :)

Comment: You can't in this form since arrays and matrices enforce uniform type (since they are both just vectors). Hence my "What you ask for doesn't exist" and also the question was about df *or* matrix.

Answer (score 1):

```
text <- "  Big Big Medium Medium Low Low
  Wet Dry    Wet    Dry Wet Dry
1   6   4      1      3   2   5
2   4   4      1      3   1   6
3   4   3      1      3   1   6
4   5   2      1      2   1   4
5   3   4      1      2   3   5"
```

You would likely read from a file, and use the `file` parameter rather than the `text` parameter that I use below:

```
labs <- read.table(header=FALSE, text=text, nrows=2)  # This will be used to construct the headers.
data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=text, skip=1)    # Consume a header line so that the row IDs are not interpreted as data.
names(data) <- apply(labs, 2, paste, collapse=',')    # Overwrite the header read above.

> data

  Big,Wet Big,Dry Medium,Wet Medium,Dry Low,Wet Low,Dry
1       6       4          1          3       2       5
2       4       4          1          3       1       6
3       4       3          1          3       1       6
4       5       2          1          2       1       4
5       3       4          1          2       3       5

> data['Big,Wet']
  Big,Wet
1       6
2       4
3       4
4       5
5       3
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives you what you asked for but is worthless for anything except visualizing:

```
dat <- read.table(text="1   6   4      1      3   2   5
2   4   4      1      3   1   6
3   4   3      1      3   1   6
4   5   2      1      2   1   4
5   3   4      1      2   3   5", header=FALSE)[, -1]

nms1 <- unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\s+", " ", "Wet Dry    Wet    Dry Wet Dry"), " "))
nms2 <- unlist(strsplit("Big Big Medium Medium Low Low", " "))

dat2 <- rbind(nms1, dat)
colnames(dat2) <- nms2

rownames(dat2) <- c(" ", 1:(nrow(dat2) - 1))
dat2
```

Yielding:

```
  Big Big Medium Medium Low Low
  Wet Dry    Wet    Dry Wet Dry
1   6   4      1      3   2   5
2   4   4      1      3   1   6
3   4   3      1      3   1   6
4   5   2      1      2   1   4
5   3   4      1      2   3   5
```

And the indexing:

```
indexer <- function(x, y) as.numeric(dat2[-1, colnames(dat2) == x & dat2[1, ] == y])
indexer("Big", "Dry")
```

This is clunky and I wouldn't go this route.  If you want functional go with the other great responses.